# Memory Used By FBO (Qglframebufferobject)

Tags: qt, opengl

I have a FBO set to 1500x1000 pixels, with Image Format of GL_RGBA8 (no textures / stencil bindings) .  I would assume the amount of memory consumed to be 4 bytes x 1.5 million + overhead.

But on Qglframebufferobject, Qt's implementation of FBO, it is consuming memory of 8 bytes x 1.5 million + overhead.

Is there a reason for this ? Or maybe I am doing something wrong (or making wrong assumption)

Comment: "*it is consuming memory of 8 bytes x 1.5 million + overhead.*" How do you know that?

Comment: What does no texture / stencil bindings mean? Are you referring to FBO attachments? Likewise, how are you measuring memory usage? APIs like ADL and NVAPI will measure video memory usage across all running processes and GPUs (_e.g._ some NV drivers count memory duplicated in SLI mode and you will get 2x memory usage in a 2-way SLI setup). You cannot get exact enough results through those APIs to conclude what you have.